# macOS - Can't load image in command line app

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I want to add my image 'test.png' to the project, to be able to load it without specifying an absolute path because when someone clones my project from git I don't want them to change this absolute path.
I tried assets: I added Media.xcassets to my project's files, and placed there an image. Then I tried to load this image that way:

```
NSImage *img = [NSImage imageNamed@"test"];
```

and it didn't work.

Comment: "it didn't work." - what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Is it the type of image that could be drawn with inline code?

Comment: @apodidae I don't want to draw that image, but just analyze it using a machine learning algorithm and then return the most popular font on the image.

Comment: @koen formalized what exactly didn't work.

Comment: @borista You still haven't explained what doesn't work. Do you get an error, does it crash, do you get an empty image, ...?

Comment: @koen img is nil. No error, no crash, just the instance is NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a command line app creates a single executable instead of a bundle, you can't automatically make other resources part of the run-time package.

One approach would be to create a Copy Files build phase that moves your image file into the Products Directory.  At that point, you can use a relative path such as:

```
NSString *relPath = @"./imageName.png"
NSImage *img = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:relPath];
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I want. Also, 'Destination' field has to be set to Products Directory and 'Subpath' field has to be cleared.